# jQuery trigger click on aspx page is not working

Tags: jquery, vb.net, triggers, clientscriptmanager

my ASPX Markup is as below

```
<a id="lnkLogin" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$LoginReg1$lnkLogin','')">Login</a>
```

And my function is as below

```
function LogOut() {
        $("#lnkLogin").trigger('click');
    }
```

for some reason this trigger click is not working?

I have also tried to do this from code behind like this

```
If Request.UrlReferrer IsNot Nothing AndAlso Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Contains("32088") Then

        ' Define the name and type of the client script on the page. 
        Dim csName As [String] = "ButtonClickScript"
        Dim csType As Type = Me.[GetType]()

        ' Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class. 
        Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

        ' Check to see if the client script is already registered. 
        If Not cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName) Then
            Dim csText As New StringBuilder()
            csText.Append("<script type=""text/javascript""> function LogOut() {")
            csText.Append("$('#lnkLogin').trigger('click');} </")
            csText.Append("script>")
            cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString())
        End If
    End If
```

but not use

Comment: why don't you just do $('#lnkLogin).click(function(){ doPostBack('ctl00$LoginReg1$lnkLogin',''); return false; });

Comment: @Evan no use(it doesn't fire and trigger click to the link)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function LogOut() {
    $("#lnkLogin")[0].click();
}
```

Comment: this gives me error "Uncaught TypeError: Object javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$LoginReg1$lnkLogin','') has no method 'click'"

Comment: How do you generate that link? Are you using `LinkButton` control?

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CausesValidation="false" />